# erro de conversão array para string

Tags: php, html

preciso inserir no banco de dados variaveis que estao numa matriz em php, escrevi o cogido:

```
    for ($i=1; $i <= 20 ; $i++) { 
    $sqlp= "INSERT INTO pergunta$i (pergunta, opcao1, valor1, opcao2, valor2, opcao3, valor3, opcao4, valor4, opcao5, valor5, opcao6, valor6, opcao7, valor8, opcao2, valor8) VALUES (`$tabela[$i][1]`,`$tabela[$i][2]`,`$tabela[$i][3]`,`$tabela[$i][4]`,`$tabela[$i][5]`,`$tabela[$i][6]`,`$tabela[$i][7]`,`$tabela[$i][8]`,`$tabela[$i][9]`,`$tabela[$i][10]`,`$tabela[$i][11]`,`$tabela[$i][12]`,`$tabela[$i][13]`,`$tabela[$i][14]`,`$tabela[$i][15]`,`$tabela[$i][16]`,`$tabela[$i][17]`,)";
        $salvar= mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlp);
}
```

quando executado, o navegador retorna erro de conversao de array para string, como posso resolver?

Comment: Pois então, se o erro está na conversão de array para string vc deveria postar essa parte do código também

Comment: o erro diz que a conversao esta nesta linha

Comment: nome da tabela pergunta$i ?? 20 tabelas?

Comment: sim, existem 20 tabelas com os nomes: pergunta1, pergunta2, pergunta3... ate 20, entao a ideia é usar o for para ir variando entre essas tabelas

Comment: certo, mas deve ter algum valor inválido na conversão. Ai só vendo lá

Comment: valor invalido em qual sentido?

Comment: Os arrays em php, quando dentro de aspas duplas, se concatena da seguinte maneira:"array: {$array['chave']}" onde as chaves indicam que ali dentro é um array.

Answer (score 1):

Assim como a utilização da vírgula é um problema recorrente para o usuário da linguagem escrita, em programação ocorre a mesma coisa.

Tem uma virgula sobrando em **,**  `$tabela[$i][17]`,)

retire a virgula antes do fechamento do parentesis   `$tabela[$i][17]`)

A VÍRGULA FATAL

A czarina russa Maria Fyodorovna certa vez salvou a vida de um homem, apenas mudando a vírgula de sua sentença de lugar. Muito inteligente, ela que não concordava com a decisão de seu marido, Alexandre II, usou o artificio a seguir.

O Czar enviou o prisioneiro para a prisão e morte no calabouço da Sibéria.

No fim da ordem de prisão vinha escrito: **“Perdão impossível, enviar para sibéria”**

Maria ordenou que redigissem nova ordem, e fingindo ler o documento original, mudou uma vírgula,  transformando a ordem em: **“Perdão, impossível enviar para Sibéria”** e o prisioneiro foi libertado.

> **É isso. Cuidado com ela. Ou com a falta dela.**

Answer (score 0):

Normamelnte esse erro ocorre quando você tenta inserir diretamente uma váriavel tipo array no query. Isso ocorre pois o banco de dados não aceita esse tipo de dados. Para gravar um array em um registro é preciso primeiro convertelo em uma string colocando um separador que pode ser qualquer caracter:

$arrayasergravado = implode ( 'separador' , $array );

Assim seu array será gravados no banco de dados.
No seu caso fica dificil afirmar qual o problema do erro pois deve se saber como você contruiu esse array que estas tentando gravar. ele é bidimensional.